# Issues trimming last word in a loop result

Tags: php

I am playing with a HackerRank exercise and this should be the result:

`61 then 62 then 63 then 64 then 65 then 66 then 67 then 68 then 69 then 70`

but I am getting a `then` after the `70`.

```
<?php

function countUp($start) {

    for ($i = 61; $i <= 70; $i++) {
        echo $i . " then ";
    }

}

$start = intval(trim(fgets(STDIN)));

countUp($start);
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**EDIT**: I tried:

```
echo "61"; 
for ($i = 62; $i <= 70; $i++) {
    echo " then ".$i;
}
```

But the test case is giving me errors:

[image]

In case you wanna try it: https://www.hackerrank.com/tests/ioa3k1bq

Comment: implode() is a handy function, add the items to an array and then join by the word 'then' as the glue

Comment: `for ($i = 61; $i <= 70; $i++) {` can be done more easily with `range(61, 70)`

Comment: `echo implode(' then ', range(61, 70));`

Comment: Another problem you may run into with this is that the function takes one argument, `$start`, but does not use it. I'd suggest using `$start` instead of a hard-coded `61`.

Comment: Based on your edit, it looks like you've run into that problem already.

Comment: checkbox confirms: "I will not consult/copy code from any source including a website, book, or friend/colleague to complete these tests, though may refer language documentation or use an IDE that has code completion features." :D

Comment: Oh you.  I've removed my answer, you cheater ;p.  Thanks for the headsup Q

Comment: "count 10 time upwards" isn't even clear if e.g. 1 to 10 or 1 to 1+10, but ok, there's a sample output 61 to 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read through your failed test. I hope this works for you.

```
<?php>

function countUp($start) {

  $FIRST_NUM = $start + 1;
  $LAST_NUM = $start + 10;

    for ($i = $FIRST_NUM; $i <= $LAST_NUM; $i++) {

        if($i == $LAST_NUM) {echo $i; break;}

        echo $i . " then ";
    }

}
$start = intval(trim(fgets(STDIN)));
countUp($start);  // try countUp(60); to test this
```

Comment: Passed! You are the winner @steven7mwesigwa. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The one-liner:

```
echo implode(' then ', range($n = intval(file_get_contents('php://stdin')), $n+9));
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this :

```
<?php

function countUp($start) {

    for ($i = 61; $i <= 70; $i++) {
        $txt.= $i . " then ";
    }
  $str= preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $txt);
  echo $str
}

$start = intval(trim(fgets(STDIN)));

countUp($start);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check when the last number is being printed and print the number without a further "then"

```
for ($i = 61; $i <= 70; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    if($i <= 69)
        echo " then ";
}
```

Another solution could use an array to enable implode(http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$numbs = [];
for ($i = 61; $i <= 70; $i++) {
    array_push($numbs, $i);
}
return implode(" then ", $numbs);
```